# Loop through Object Keys and append string to the key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a config object. Using this config object, I populate required elements by appending a string to the key of this object.I need help updating values

```
const MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE = {
  type: '',
  dateOfBirth_: '',
  seekingCoverage_: true,
  relationshipToPrimary: ''
}; 

const updateInitialValue = (type, relationshipToPrimary) => { 
  var newMemberObjValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE));
  let updateValue =  Object.entries(newMemberObjValue).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      [`${key}_${type}`]: value; //I'm stuck here. not sure how to proceed
      delete key;

  });
  return updateValue;
};

updateInitialValue = ('applicant', 'SELF');
updateInitialValue = ('spouse', 'DEPENDANT');
```

## Expected Result:

```
{
  type: 'applicant',
  dateOfBirth_applicant: '',
  seekingCoverage_applicant: true
  relationshipToPrimary: 'SELF'
}; 
{
  type: 'spouse',
  dateOfBirth_spouse: '',
  seekingCoverage_spouse: true
  relationshipToPrimary: 'DEPENDANT'
};
```

Comment: I'm curious about the general design of this approach. Since you have the type as a property on the object, why do you need to update the object's keys to include the type? Depending on how this object is used, that's a brittle approach, as you're requiring a maintenance overhead to keep the object's keys aligned with the type at all times. Also, to my view, deleting keys is a code smell.

Comment: @somewhatsapient I need to update this object because these keys are associated with the checkbox. As the checkbox gets updated, these values need to be updated.

Comment: but you're not actually updating the initial object, correct?

Comment: I'm not updating the initial object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not updating the original object, you can simplify this greatly:

```
const MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE = {
  type: '',
  dateOfBirth_: '',
  seekingCoverage_: true,
  relationshipToPrimary: ''
};

const updateInitialValue = (type, relationshipToPrimary) => ({
  type,
  relationshipToPrimary,
  [`dateOfBirth_${type}`]: MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE.dateOfBirth_,
  [`seekingCoverage_${type}`]: MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE.seekingCoverage_
});

let updatedValue = updateInitialValue('applicant', 'SELF');
updatedValue = updateInitialValue('spouse', 'DEPENDANT');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
const MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE = {
  type: '',
  dateOfBirth_: '',
  seekingCoverage_: true,
  relationshipToPrimary: ''
};

const updateInitialValue = (type, relationshipToPrimary) => {
    let newMemberInitialValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE));
  Object.keys(newMemberInitialValue).forEach((key) => {
    if(!['type', 'relationshipToPrimary'].includes(key)) {
        newMemberInitialValue[`${key}_${type}`] = newMemberInitialValue[key];
     delete newMemberInitialValue[key];
    }
  });
  newMemberInitialValue.type = type;
  newMemberInitialValue.relationshipToPrimary = relationshipToPrimary;
  console.log(newMemberInitialValue);
};

let applicantValues = updateInitialValue('applicant', 'SELF');
let spouseValues = updateInitialValue('spouse', 'DEPENDANT');
```

**EDIT:** Missed returning the value from the function and then assigning to a new variable.

Comment: I see what you're going for, but the updated value isn't returned from the function nor assigned to a variable. How do the changes made to the internal variable `newMemberInitialValue` make it outside the scope of the function?

Comment: My bad at that. The `newMemberInitialValue` variable needs to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Although an answer was posted, because i also solved it and my solution is a bit different (though the other answer looks way too slimmer) i would post it here.

```
const MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE = {
  type: "",
  dateOfBirth_: "",
  seekingCoverage_: true,
  relationshipToPrimary: "",
};

const updateInitialValue = (type, relationshipToPrimary) => {
  var newMemberObjValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MEMBER_INITIAL_VALUE));

  Object.entries(newMemberObjValue).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === "type") {
      newMemberObjValue[key] = type;
    } else if (key === "dateOfBirth_") {
      Object.defineProperty(
        newMemberObjValue,
        [`${key}_${type}`],
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newMemberObjValue, key)
      );
      delete newMemberObjValue[key];
      newMemberObjValue[`${key}_${type}`] = value;
    } else if (key === "seekingCoverage_") {
      Object.defineProperty(
        newMemberObjValue,
        [`${key}_${type}`],
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newMemberObjValue, key)
      );
      delete newMemberObjValue[key];
      newMemberObjValue[`${key}_${type}`] = value;
    } else if (key === "relationshipToPrimary") {
      newMemberObjValue[key] = relationshipToPrimary;
    }
  });

  return newMemberObjValue;
};

const updatedValue1 = updateInitialValue("applicant", "SELF");
const updatedValue2 = updateInitialValue('spouse', 'DEPENDANT');
```

Comment: This is overly complex and will also result in keys like `seekingCoverage__type` with a double underscore. Also, what are you doing with the return value from this object?

Comment: I would also recommend against using the approach of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` to make a copy of an object, as the stringifying and parsing methods run a risk of actually modifying key or value strings.

Comment: of course the returned value should be stored in a variable. My main goal was to focus on the function itself. tho i will edit my answer with the returned value stored in a variable to not make it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Though a few answers have already been posted, I would like to suggest a similar one that does the same thing in a much more clear and concise way:

```js
function Member() {
  this.type = '';
    this.dateOfBirth = '';
    this.seekingCoverage = true;
    this.relationshipToPrimary = '';
}

function UpdateInitialValue(type, relationshipToPrimary) {
  var newMember = new Member();
  newMember.type = type;
  newMember.relationshipToPrimary = relationshipToPrimary;
  return newMember;
}

console.log(UpdateInitialValue('applicant', 'SELF'));
console.log(UpdateInitialValue('spouse', 'DEPENDANT'));
```